# Upgrade from 7-speed SunRace to 10 speed Deore: can I use the same wheel?

Tags: cassette

I got a whole Shimano Deore groupset 3 x 10 and would like to upgrade my good old Trek bike. Do I need to change the whole rear wheel now? It has currently Sunrace Megadrive Lock Ring Type cassette or rather a freewheel. 
And if I need a new wheel, what should I get so that it lasts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to:

1. Maybe [respace](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html) the rear dropouts, depending on the age of the frame. Modern wheels are wider than older wheels. For reference, 7 speed road is 126 mm, 7 speed mountain is 130 mm, 10 speed road is 130 mm and 10 speed mountain is 135 mm. Note that your frame needs to be steel for respacing to work -- if it isn't steel, you risk frame failure.
2. Get a new wheel -- something which has a Shimano-compatible 10/11 speed freehub (11 speed will also work with 10 speed). You *could* just buy the hub and rebuild your existing wheel with it, but you need a hub designed for the same number of spokes, likely all new spokes of the new correct lengths, and someone whose got experience doing it. Overall, in cost and reliability, getting a new wheel is probably a better bet.

Comment: I measured the frame and the spacing is 135 mm, which gives at least some hope that the frame will take it.

Comment: I'm not sure you measured correctly. What model Trek is it?

Comment: It is TREK 3700 purchased in 2007. I measured according to this instruction http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html using a precision measuring tool.

Comment: Okay, that's a pretty new bike. I'd believe that has 135 mm spacing. So you just need to buy a new rear wheel.

Comment: I believe this kind of hub would work http://www.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/mtb1/wheels---hubs/rear-hubs/fh-m615-s.html even though the bike has V-brakes, not disc brakes.

Comment: Well, you should just buy a 10 speed mountain wheel with the rim supporting rim brakes.